# How to change background color to specific inputs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, background-color

I'm making a Sudoku game, and when I click on an input it highlights the row, the column and the box where you are introducing a value. I also have a mouse hover that highlights the same things I previously mentioned but with different colour. The hover works fine, the problem here is when after clicking on an input it doesn't change all the box color to "transparent", I have to hover the mouse for updating the color and it's a bit ugly to do that.

Here is the code:

```js
function hoverByClass(classname, colorover, colorover2, colorout) {
  let t1 = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
  /* console.log(classname); */
  for (let i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    t1[i].onmouseover = function() {
      for (let k = 0; k < t1.length; k++) {
        t1[k].style.backgroundColor = colorover;
        /* console.log(t1[k]);
        console.log(k); */
      }
    }
    t1[i].onmouseout = function() {
      for (let x = 0; x < t1.length; x++) {
        t1[x].style.backgroundColor = colorout;
      }
    }

    t1[i].onclick = function() {
      for (let j = 0; j < t1.length; j++) {
        /* console.log(t1[j]); */
        t1[j].style.backgroundColor = colorover2;
      }
    }
  }
}
for (let index = 1; index <= 9; index++) {
  hoverByClass("fila" + index, "#add8e6", "#8a2be2", "transparent");
  hoverByClass("columna" + index, "#add8e6", "#8a2be2", "transparent");
}

let sdk = document.getElementsByName('sdk[]');
for (let x = 0; x < sdk.length; x++) {
  sdk[x].onclick = function() {
    clic = sdk[x];
    /*console.log(clic);*/
    clic.style.backgroundColor = "#8a2be2";
    let t2 = document.getElementsByClassName(sdk[x].classList[0]);
    for (let j = 0; j < t2.length; j++) {
      /*console.log(t2[j]);*/
      t2[j].style.backgroundColor = "#8a2be2";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

.tG {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  TEXT-ALIGN: center;
  border: none;
}

.normal {
  border: gray 0.1px solid;
}

.abajo {
  border: gray 0.1px solid;
  border-bottom: blueviolet 2px solid;
}

.derecha {
  border: gray 0.1px solid;
  border-right: blueviolet 2px solid;
}

.derbajo {
  border: gray 0.1px solid;
  border-right: blueviolet 2px solid;
  border-bottom: blueviolet 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="tG" align="center">
  <tr class="fila1">
    <td class="normal columna1 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna1"></td>
    <td class="normal columna2 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna3 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna3"></td>
    <td class="normal columna4 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna4"></td>
    <td class="normal columna5 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna6 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna6"></td>
    <td class="normal columna7 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna7"></td>
    <td class="normal columna8 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna8"></td>
    <td class="normal columna9 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila2">
    <td class="normal columna1 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna1"></td>
    <td class="normal columna2 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna3 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna3"></td>
    <td class="normal columna4 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna4"></td>
    <td class="normal columna5 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna6 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna6"></td>
    <td class="normal columna7 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna7"></td>
    <td class="normal columna8 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna8"></td>
    <td class="normal columna9 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila3">
    <td class="abajo columna1 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna1"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna2 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derbajo columna3 t1"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t1 columna3"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna4 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna4"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna5 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derbajo columna6 t2"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t2 columna6"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna7 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna7"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna8 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna8"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna9 t3"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t3 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila4">
    <td class="normal columna1 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna1"></td>
    <td class="normal columna2 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna3 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna3"></td>
    <td class="normal columna4 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna4"></td>
    <td class="normal columna5 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna6 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna6"></td>
    <td class="normal columna7 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna7"></td>
    <td class="normal columna8 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna8"></td>
    <td class="normal columna9 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila5">
    <td class="normal columna1 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna1"></td>
    <td class="normal columna2 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna3 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna3"></td>
    <td class="normal columna4 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna4"></td>
    <td class="normal columna5 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna6 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna6"></td>
    <td class="normal columna7 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna7"></td>
    <td class="normal columna8 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna8"></td>
    <td class="normal columna9 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila6">
    <td class="abajo columna1 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna1"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna2 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derbajo columna3 t4"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t4 columna3"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna4 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna4"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna5 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derbajo columna6 t5"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t5 columna6"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna7 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna7"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna8 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna8"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna9 t6"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t6 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila7">
    <td class="normal columna1 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna1"></td>
    <td class="normal columna2 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna3 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna3"></td>
    <td class="normal columna4 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna4"></td>
    <td class="normal columna5 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna6 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna6"></td>
    <td class="normal columna7 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna7"></td>
    <td class="normal columna8 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna8"></td>
    <td class="normal columna9 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila8">
    <td class="normal columna1 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna1"></td>
    <td class="normal columna2 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna3 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna3"></td>
    <td class="normal columna4 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna4"></td>
    <td class="normal columna5 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derecha columna6 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna6"></td>
    <td class="normal columna7 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna7"></td>
    <td class="normal columna8 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna8"></td>
    <td class="normal columna9 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila9">
    <td class="abajo columna1 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna1"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna2 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna2"></td>
    <td class="derbajo columna3 t7"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t7 columna3"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna4 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna4"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna5 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna5"></td>
    <td class="derbajo columna6 t8"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t8 columna6"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna7 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna7"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna8 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna8"></td>
    <td class="abajo columna9 t9"><input name="sdk[]" size="1" maxlength="1" class="t9 columna9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how it looks when clicking on an input
[image]

The problem is this when I move my cursor to other part of the grid:
[image]

More examples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is great and I am interested, but I find it's still incomplete for understanding purpose.

Comment: Instead of assigning a backgroundColor to the style of each element you could give them a class of purple, for example.  Then, when it’s time to remove the purple, simply make a querySelectorAll that targets all elements with class of purple and remove that class.